# Flexslider в повторителе ACF не выводит изображения

Tags: wordpress, slider, acf

Имеем повторитель ACF на странице.
В нем, помимо прочего, - Flexslider

```
<?php
                // проверяем есть ли в повторителе данные
                if( have_rows('projects') ):
                    // перебираем данные
                while ( have_rows('projects') ) : the_row();
                ?>
                <div class="slider-sections">
                    <div class="slider-box">
                      <div class="container-planners">
                            <h4><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h4>
                            <div class="slider-big">
                            <?php 
                            $images = get_sub_field('gallery');
                            if( $images ): 
                            ?>
                                <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                                    <ul class="slides">
                                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                            <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                                    <ul class="slides">
                                            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                                    <li>
                                                            <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                                    </li>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="info-box-slider">
                  <div class="price-box">
                    <h5><?php the_sub_field('under-titile-1'); ?></h5>
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('price-1'); ?></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price-box">
                    <h5><?php the_sub_field('under-titile-2'); ?></h5>
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('price-2'); ?></p>
                  </div>
                  <span><?php the_sub_field('house_cost'); ?></span>
                  <div class="btn-box">
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('dostavka'); ?></p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn-order">ОСТАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                                <ul class="slides">
                                    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-line">
                        <div class="container-planners">
                            <div class="info-line-flex">
                            <?php
                                // проверяем есть ли в повторителе данные
                                if( have_rows('chars') ):
                                    // перебираем данные
                                while ( have_rows('chars') ) : the_row();
                            ?>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <h2><?php the_sub_field('title_ch'); ?></h2>
                                    <p><?php the_sub_field('text_ch'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                                endwhile;
                                endif;
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                    endwhile;

                    else :
                
                    // вложенных полей не найдено
                
                endif;
                
                ?>
```

Повторитель работает исправно.
В момент загрузки страницы изображения из слайдера появляются и исчезают.
При просмотре кода в инспекторе слайдер виден, но у всех слайдов visibility: hidden

Рядом стоит такой же слайдер просто на HTML, и он работает.

Но! У HTML слайдера при его работе в код подгружаются дополнительные элементы и стили.
А у ACF варианта - нет.

Как победить?

Comment: `visibility: hidden` явно не связано с ACF и PHP как таковым. Вы уверены что ID уникальны для слайдеров? Потому что у Вас в цикле есть элементы с ID-шниками (`id="slider"`, `id="carousel"`).

Comment: К тому же `id="carousel"` встречается в коде два раза и зачем два цикла с `$images` не совсем понятно.

Comment: Согласен. С ID тут проблема. И как ее обойти - непонятно. Поставил рядом через ACF еще один слайдер с индивидуальным ID. Без повторителя и дополнительных полей. Эффект тот же самый. Встраиваю слайдер в соответствии с рекомендациями ACF. Т.е. проблема первая именно в ACF. А вторая, - как разрулить ситуацию с ID.

Comment: Два цикла - именно по рекомендации ACF. Т.е. тупо их код перекопировал. Даже классы сохранил, и стилизовал уже под них.

Comment: Обойти ее можно имея уникальный ID или инитить слайдер по классу, а не ID или получить нужные элменты и ивлечь оттуда ID атрибуты, вариантов уйма. `Т.е. проблема первая именно в ACF` -- это какая?

Comment: Собственно сьраница: https://mirbaum.ru/planners/

Comment: Да не выводит он изображения. В отдельно взятом слайдере с ID = как положено.

Comment: Хотя.... Поковыряюсь еще.

Comment: Еще раз, `visibility: hidden` не имеет отношения к ACF и бекенду, это развешивается JS-ом. Если при инспекции HTML если код на месте и `img` тег имеет валидную ссылку в `src` атрибуте, то все он Вам выводит, а дальше просто отрабатывает Ваш JS код. ACF или PHP как и любому другому бекенд коду глубоко все равно, какой там ID атрибут у какого элемента, так как в данном случае они не взаимодействуют. Чтобы проверить выводит ли он изображения, просто выведите вне слайдера таким же циклом картинки. Код простой как двери.

Comment: В HTML у нас слайдер создается в плагине.  и там же он инициализируется. Через ACF мы его выводим через поле ГАЛЕРЕЯ. Я проинициализировал отдельно выведенный через ACF слайдер. Картинки на странице появились. Только это не слайдер. Не подгрузилась пагинация. Вывелись все картинки. И куда копать теперь?

Comment: Копать в JS и в то как выводите.